# Error occured while import tensorflow in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow version 2.2.0 in my windows.But it shows the following error while i want to import it.How can i solve the problem?

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

G:\anaconda\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

G:\anaconda\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5e7c1303e954> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow
      2 
      3 train_examples = tf.keras.utils.normalize(new_train, axis=1)
      4 
      5 test_examples = tf.keras.utils.normalize(new_test, axis=1)

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "G:\anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "G:\anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
2. download x64: vc_redist.x64.exe
3. install it.

*Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749#issuecomment-588425399*

=====

Another possible solution is downgrading to tensorflow 2.0

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

*Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749#issuecomment-573313402*